# Can Massive .NET ORM work on Mono for Linux?

Tags: orm, mono, massive

Can the [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) .NET ORM work on [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) for Linux? If so what would need to be setup?

Comment: I'm not trying to be sarcastic here but I guess there is one way to find out. Drop one of the code files (determined by the DBMS you are using) in your project and see if it compiles [and works]. Since the code is so small it'd probably be painless to perform a simple check on your own.

Comment: I don't have a mono/linux setup at the moment. I was hoping someone else already had tried it. If I don't hear from anyone that has tried it after awhile I'll break down and do it. Right now I just don't have a ton of time.

Comment: I have a VirtualBox VM with ArchLinux, I can give it a shot tonight and see what happens.

Comment: I was able to compile Massive.PostgreSQL.cs using Mono 2.10.6. I have not had time to see if it works yet but it does compile.

Comment: cool thanks! that helps just need keep fingers crossed it'll work at runtime.

Comment: I should have time to play with it tonight to see if it works. I'll report back as soon as I try it.

Comment: Massive.Sqlite appears to be working on Mono 2.10.6. I've got some basic querying working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to build Massive.Sqlite on Mono 2.6.10 and get selects, inserts, updates and deletes working. I haven't tried anything else yet. You can look at the examples on how to do that stuff here:

https://github.com/robconery/massive

A couple points to note are that you have to change two lines so they work with Mono.Data.Sqlite instead of System.Data.Sqlite.

Replace

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
```

with

```
using Mono.Data.SQLite;
```

I also had to change line 128 from:

```
var _providerName = "System.Data.SQLite";
```

to

```
var _providerName = "Mono.Data.SQLite";
```

If you are using MonoDevelop and create a new project you'll need to set it to use the .NET 4 profile and then add the following references to your project:

```
Microsoft.CSharp
Mono.Data.Sqlite
System.Configuration
```

Comment: awesome! if you happen to test MySql and it works post it here for everyone. thanks!

Comment: I'll play with it some more tonight. I'll let you know.

Comment: I am using MySql with Mono from master (soon to be Mono 2.12) and it works fine. No tweaks required!

Answer (score 0):

Try Vega https://github.com/aadreja/vega. One of the best & fastest .net ORM with enterprise features. It supports both .net core and .net and works like a charm on linux.